# How to return value that is i relation of list. If value come from input

Tags: python, python-3.x

in def karakter i want to return the value if its in relation to a elemtent in the list karak. Let's say i the input of valg_emne is INFO132, I want it then to return element B. If input valg_emne is INFO100 i want it to return C and so on.

```
print('\nVelkommen til karakterprogrammet\n')
        print('----------------------------')

        print('1: Emneliste','2: Legg til emne','3: Sett karakter','4: Karaktersnitt','5: Avslutt',sep='\n')
        print('----------------------------')

        emner = ['INFO100','INFO132','INFO233']
        FagKoder = ['informasjonsvitenskap','økonomi']
        karak = [['INFO100','C'],['INFO132','B'],['INFO233','C']]
        emnenivåer = [100,200,300,400]

        def start():
            global meny
            global fag
            meny = int(input('Tast inn ønsket valg (press 0 for meny): '))

            if meny == 1:
              valg_fag = input('Press Enter for å velge fag eller emnenivå ("alle" for å vise alle fag/emner): ')

            if meny == 1 and valg_fag == 'alle':
              for i in karak:
                  print(*i)

            elif meny == 1 and valg_fag == '':
              fag = input('- Fag: ')
              emnenivå = int(input('- Emnenivå: '))

              if fag in emner and emnenivå in emnenivåer:
                fag = fag
                emennivå = emnenivå
                print('Hallo')
              else:
                print('1234')


        def legg_til():
            global meny
            global fag
            if meny == 2:
              add = input('Nytt emne:  ')
              emner.append(add.upper())


        def karakter():
            global meny
            if meny == 3:
              valg_emne = input('Emne: ')
              slett = input('Karakter (<enter> for å slette): '+ karak[0][1])

            if meny == 3 and slett in karak:
              print(karak)


        start()
        legg_til()
        karakter()
```

Comment: i have just used python for 4 weeks and im not that good yet.

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in range(len(karak)):
    if karak[i][0]==valg_emne:
        print (karak[i][1])
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to look up the pairs in `karak` in a loop, check the first part and if it matches print the second part:

```
for one_karak in karak:
    if one_karak[0] == valg_emne:
        print(one_karak[1])
        break
```

There is an even easier solution, if you can change the structure of `karak` to a dictionary:

```
karak = {'INFO100': 'C', 'INFO132': 'B', 'INFO233': 'C'}
```

Then you can just access it as:

```
try:
    print(karak[valg_emne])
except KeyError:
    print('Input not in karak')
```